# Use protobuf in Android NDK using CMake

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I need to use the `protobuf` library in the c++ code of android ndk. In other words, let my auto-generated `something.pb.h` be happy when it wants to include files like `#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>`.

I do see some methods, but they all use the old `Android.mk` approach, while I need to use the new `CMakeLists.txt` approach (and there is completely no such thing as `Android.mk` in my project).

Therefore, what should I do? Thanks for any suggestions!

---

What I have tried:

Firstly `brew install protobuf`. Then, in CMakelists.txt

```
SET(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/include/")
# have also tried this: find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
# have also tried this: find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(protobuf REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using Protocol Buffers ${Protobuf_VERSION}")

target_link_libraries(vision_utils
        ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
        # have also tried this: protobuf::libprotobuf
)
```

but various errors with different attempts above:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "protobuf" with any
of the following names:
```

or

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:107 (add_library):
Target "vision_utils" links to target "protobuf::libprotobuf" but the
target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Comment: It seems that [formula for protobuf](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/protobuf.rb) uses `./configure` way for built the project. That way doesn't create `protobuf-config.cmake` file which is needed for `find_package(Protobuf)` to work. The needed file is created when protobuf is built using CMake: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/cmake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks! I am not very familiar with cmake, so could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Tsyvarev in addition I am on macos, but the README you mentioned is for windows.

Comment: Yes, that README mentions Windows, but it should work on other platforms too. Actually, CMake itself provides script [FindProtobuf.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html), so it can be used for `find_package(Protobuf)` instead of script `protobuf-config.cmake`. Correct call is `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)`, and if your CMake version is 3.9 or newer, then this call should create IMPORTED target `protobuf::libprotobuf`. (For lower CMake versions use variables `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `Protobuf_LIBRARIES`).

Comment: I have tried it but does not work, as shown in the question :(

Comment: In the question I see **two error messages**. So, which one is applicable to attempt `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)`? BTW, it would be easy to understand correspondence of between the code and the error message, would you **not mix** attempts. E.g.: "The code <code1> causes error <error message1>. The code <code2> causes error <error message 2>. Which CMake version do you use and what is written in `cmake_minumum_required`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks very much for your kind help! Indeed, about 2 hours ago, I gave up on using protobuf and use json instead (because it is so difficult to compile protobuf... while using json is a simple matter of `#include "json.hpp"`). Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Try generating protobuf buildfiles manually with

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" \
 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE={NDK PATH}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
 -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM={NDK PATH}/prebuilt/{YOUR PLATFORM}/bin/make \
 -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
  {PROTOBUF SOURCE PATH}/cmake
```

build

```
cmake --build . --target libprotobuf
```

then in `CMakeLists.txt` set

```
set(Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR {{PROTOBUF SOURCE PATH}/src}) 
set(Protobuf_LIBRARIES {build files path})
```

Got this solution from [here](https://programmerall.com/article/72641194122/)